# Docker Run Permission Issue while setting up volume

Tags: docker

I have created a folder my-jenkins-data and changed the permission to `chown -R 1000 /root/my-jenkins-data` but I get a "permission denied" error when I try to access the bind-mounted directory from a container.

Here is the quick snippet of the command:

```
[root@osboxes /]# sudo chown -R 1000 /root/my-jenkins-data
[root@osboxes /]# sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /root/my-jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has non-root user that is `jenkins`.

Try to run

```
chown -R 1000:1000 /root/my-jenkins-data
```

Or you can give all permissions to the folder.

```
chmod -R 777 /root/my-jenkins-data
```

Or you can create docker volume and attach to Jenkins.

```
docker volume create jenkins
docker run -p 8033:8080 -v jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -u root jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

To list volume folder execute get folder location with `docker volume inspect jenkins`

```
$ docker volume inspect jenkins
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-01-02T22:13:07+03:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins/_data",
        "Name": "jenkins",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

$ ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins/_data
```

Comment: I believe the UID of the Jenkins user is 1000. Besides.777 is rarely the answer to anything other than as a quick hacky test to confirm that permissions are the problem.

Comment: I know that is 1000. I think giving all permissions is acceptable when the server is isolated.

Comment: @SiHa I have added working solution as first.